# HTML 5 drag events: 'dragleave' fired after 'dragenter'

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using html5 dragevents in a single page application.

Currently, I'm listening to the `dragleave` and `dragenter` events to set the proper classes on the elements.

But, when two valid target elements(A and B) are next to each other, and we drag an elment through A into B, the events are fired in the following sequance.

```
                     +--------------+-------------+
                     |              |             |
+-------+            |     A        |     B       |
|       |            |              |             |
| Elem  +------------------------------------>    |
|       |            |              |             |
+-------+            |              |             |
                     +--------------+-------------+
```

1. `dragenter` of A
2. `dragenter` of B
3. `dragleave` of A

The expected order of the events would be,

1. `dragenter` of A
2. `dragleave` of A
3. `dragenter` of B

I assumed that this would be the order since the item has to leave `A` before entering `B`. Am I missing something here? Is there a rationale for the `dragenter` being fired before the `dragleave`? Is there a way to change this behaviour?

I have a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nipuna777/drp1cgar/12/).

The code itself is pretty simple with the `dragenter` and `dragover` being listened to.

```
dragenter: function(e) {
    console.log("basket dragenter");
    // logic here
},
dragleave: function(e) {
    console.log("basket dragleave");
    // logic here
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late to the party but, here is my use case. Imagine that B is entirely enclosed in A:

```
             +---------------------------+
             |  A                        |
             |      +---------------+    |
+-----+      |      | B             |    |
|     |      |      |               |    |
|    -|------|------|--->           |    |
+-----+      |      |               |    |
             |      |               |    |
             |      +---------------+    |
             +---------------------------+
```

You can leave A here by leaving it entirely, or by leaving it to go to B. The fact that B.dragenter is fired before A.dragleave allows you to be aware of the direction of the drag in the A.dragleave handler.

In fact I just realise that the same goes for your use-case: you can leave A to the void (left-up-down) or to go to B (right).

Note that the above is my interpretation of 'why' this is useful. The behaviour itself confirmed by this section of the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But, if we move the boxes slightly apart, and drag the item through fast enough, the 'dragEnter' would still be fired before 'dragLeave'. Not sure if this is  a browser issue but this can be re-created in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/po8Ls9z2/

Comment: Hm, interesting point. I guess you have to work around it, because I don't think it is incorrect behaviour. I think this part of the spec is relevant:


"
If the user agent is still performing the previous iteration of the sequence (if any) when the next iteration becomes due, abort these steps for this iteration (effectively "skipping missed frames" of the drag-and-drop operation).
"