# How to prevent dragleave interfering with dragenter event on nested dropzone element?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

With two nested elements in `dropzone` and dragging from outer to inner element, `dragleave` actions take precedence over `dragenter`.

I have initially one div as `dropzone`, which on dragenter changes class ('canDrop') to indicate if drop is possible, while on dragleave the class reverts to neutral ('plainDropZone').

On drop the `draggable` div becomes a child of the `dropzone` div. Now, when another `draggable` enters the `dropzone`, class is changed to 'noDrop' to indicate no more drops are possible. On `dragleave` the class reverts to neutral again ('plainDropZone')

The Problem: When dragging from outer `dropzone` div to the inner dropped div, the outer `dropzone` div should not revert to neutral, but still have the class 'noDrop'.

As far as I have found out this does not work as intended, because when moving from outer to inner div, `dragleave` gets fired after `dragenter`. This thread visualizes the problem nicely: [HTML 5 drag events: 'dragleave' fired after 'dragenter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275189/html-5-drag-events-dragleave-fired-after-dragenter)

Here is a full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e12uadgh/

So what would be a way to assign the outer `dropzone` div the class 'noDrop', when it has a dropped inner div and the user drags a third div from outer `dropzone` div to inner dropped div?

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to achieve the effect. When dragging an element from outer dropzone div to inner dropzone div, `dragleave` for outer div  is fired after `dragenter` for inner div, so that any changes on `dragenter` get overridden by the changes made on `dragleave`.

So one solution is to make only changes on `dragleave`, if the next event target is not the inner div. Since this can not be done by examining `event.target` on `dragleave`, we can use a toggle instead, which is set to true on `dragenter` on inner div, and which becomes false on `dragleave` on inner div.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rookie_sen/2Lp5qg39/5/