# With HTML5 can an element be made 'invisible' for drag/drop interaction?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, event-handling

Still trying to [combine drag&drop and moving an element with the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71554042/how-to-move-an-html-elment-with-the-mouse-inside-parent-but-drag-drop-outside-of) I'm struggling with `dragenter` and `dragleave` not being called for a parent element when I'm moving the child element. This seems quite natural because the element always hovers over the parent element and prevents `dragenter` being called for the parent.

I tried to call `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` in `dragenter`, `dragleave`, `dragover`, `dragstart` and `drag` events for the child element but with no real effect.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959713/how-to-prevent-dragleave-interfering-with-dragenter-event-on-nested-dropzone-ele) seems to address a similar issue but with no real solution if I get this correctly.

Maybe it's just too dark down here in the rabbit hole to see the obvious - how do I prevent the dragged item from avoiding its parents `dragenter`/`dragleave` events to be called?

On another level I just want to know if the element has been dropped outside the parent element (to then return it to it's original position). Is there an easier approach?

[Here is my current code](https://jsfiddle.net/03a9s4ur/4/) - In the current state the element is being moved with the mouse and thus preventing `dragenter` or `dragleave` being called.

[Deactivating the actual movement of `draggable_element`](https://jsfiddle.net/03a9s4ur/5/) will make `dragenter` and `dragleave` be called when leaving the parent/target area but also when the dragged element is being entered (what I somehow can't avoid).

Comment: Please convert this into an actual [mcve] (remove the commented code, anything that's not directly related to the problem (e.g. the JSON stuff), ...) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And this would be the perfect use-case for a snippet -> [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: A [mcve] doesn't mean you should remove the complete code and hide it on an external resource -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: I got you -  just takes me some time to refactor the code, I'm  on it!

Comment: I minimalized the code now - some comments are still there but they are just for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Found it - instead fiddling with the drag/drop events you just have to deactivate `pointer-events` for the dragged item to avoid unwanted `dragenter`/`dragleave` events for the parent and turn it back on again afterwards (it has to be activated by default to enable dragging in the first place).

```js
draggable_element.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  e.srcElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  ... // rest of code
});

elem.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
  e.srcElement.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  ... // rest of code
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/03a9s4ur/10/